# Is square brackets use with checkbox input elements PHP-only?

Tags: php, checkbox, square-bracket

Given a construct like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="red" name="color[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="green" name="color[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="blue" name="color[]" />
```

if POST'ed to a PHP page the `$_POST` super-global will add the values of the checked checkboxes to an array `color`.

Is this a PHP-only convention or do other web-aware languages follow it also? If the latter, what other languages/libraries follow this convention?

Comment: I've never seen it anywhere else then PHP yet, but that doesn't mean much of course :)

Comment: Classic ASP will give you one field (not an array) with comma-separated values whenever you have HTML elements sharing a name. That's not exactly the same as PHP, but gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it in ASP.NET MVC but it usually needs an index added, eg `name="color[0]"`, `name="color[1]"`, etc

Example here - [Wits End with IDictionary<T,T> and ModelBinders, ASP.NET MVC 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983347/wits-end-with-idictionaryt-t-and-modelbinders-asp-net-mvc-2-0/3983364#3983364)